# Callback after for-loop finishes in node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, callback

I need some help with the asynchronous nature of node.js. I have a for loop, which collects data from the database. "result" is an array, which should then be returned to the main function.

```
user_collection.findOne({
            _id : uid
        }, function(error, user) {
            if(error)
                callback(error)
            else {
                for(var j = 0; j < user.contacts.length; j++) {
                    if(user.contacts[j].accepted == 'true') {
                        user_collection.findOne({
                            _id : user.contacts[j].contactId
                        }, function(error, user) {
                            result.push(user);
                        })
                    } 
                }
                callback(null, result);  // This callback executes before the for-loop ends, ofc
            }
        });
```

How can I ensure that the callback executes after the loop finished?

Comment: Working version with async: `user_collection.findOne({
    _id : userId
   }, function(error, user) {
    if(error)
     callback(error)
    else {
     async.forEach(user.contacts, function(contact,callback) {
      console.log(contact);
      if(contact.accepted == 'true') {
       user_collection.findOne({
        _id : contact.contactId
       }, function(error, contact) {
        result.push(contact);
        callback();
       })
      }
     }, function(error) { callback(error, result) })
    }
   });`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You might want to consider using helper library like **async** 
https://github.com/caolan/async

It helps keep code more consistent..

In your case, you can look at the [forEach()](http://caolan.github.io/async/docs.html#.eachOf) method

```
forEach(arr, iterator, callback)
```

The iterator is called with an item from the list and a callback for when it has finished.

Checkout the unit tests for examples

https://github.com/caolan/async/blob/master/mocha_test/each.js

Answer (score 2):

Using ES6 Promises
(a promise library can be used for older browsers):

Process all requests guaranteeing synchronous execution (e.g. 1 then 2 then 3)

```
function asyncFunction (item, cb) {
  setTimeout(() => {
    console.log('done with', item);
    cb();
  }, 100);
}

let requests = [1, 2, 3].reduce((promiseChain, item) => {
    return promiseChain.then(new Promise((resolve) => {
      asyncFunction(item, resolve);
    }));
}, Promise.resolve());

requests.then(() => console.log('done'))
```

Process all async requests without "synchronous" execution (2 may finish faster than 1)

```
let requests = [1,2,3].map((item) => {
    return new Promise((resolve) => {
      asyncFunction(item, resolve);
    });
})

Promise.all(requests).then(() => console.log('done'));
```

I did it on that way

```
Promise.all(body.schedules.map(function(scheduleId) {
        return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
            return scheduleSchema.findOneAndRemove({
                    _id: scheduleId
                })
                .then(function() {
                    logSchema.insert({
                        userId: req.user.id,
                        actId: constants.LOG_SCHEDULE_DELETE.id,
                        extData: scheduleId
                    });
                    resolve();
                })
                .catch(function(err) {
                    reject(err);
                });
        });
    })).then(function() {
        return res.json({
            code: constants.SUCCESS_CODE
        });
    }).catch(function(err) {
        return res.json(constants.DATABASE_ERROR);
    });
```

The last example

```
function callback (result) { console.log('all done'); }

[1, 2, 3].forEach((item, index, array) => {
  asyncFunction(item, () => {
    if (index === array.length - 1) {
      callback();
    }
  });
});
```

This does not guarantee that callback will execute after all items are processed. It only guarantees that callback will execute after the very last item is processed.

[More information](https://codedump.io/share/2dw91w0HFcjx/1/callback-after-all-asynchronous-foreach-callbacks-are-completed)

Michael.

Answer (score 0):

With v1.5.2 of Async.js, It is [each](https://github.com/caolan/async#eacharr-iterator-callback).

```
each(arr, iterator, [callback])
```

**arr** - An array to iterate over.
**iterator(item, callback)** - A function to apply to each item in arr.
**callback(err)** - Optional. A callback which is called when *all iterator functions have finished, or an error occurs*.